# How can I enable set the timeout on file uploads in SWF to greater than 3 min?

Tags: flash, timeout, file-upload

I'm using SWFUpload to handle file uploads and have run into a problem where any file upload >= 3 min will time out. As far as I can tell, Apache and PHP are configured properly to handle large files. Are there any settings with Flash that might affect this? Does Flash have some sort of timeout value I could change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PHP script is timing out, then you can adjust the php time_limit by calling set_time_limit(int seconds). If you set it equal to -1 then the script will execute indefinitely, if that's what you want / need.

If the Flash is timing out, you might want to take a look at the following:

http://www.aflax.org/forums/topic.php?id=38

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-262299.html